# jQuery - split string by symbol and get last part

Tags: jquery, arrays, string

If I have a list of bank account numbers such as the following :

```
<span>6456465465/0471</span>
<span>4547/6456465465/0471</span>
<span>4547/6465465/0471</span>
```

How can I get the last four digits from each of these? Some bank accounts have a prefix, some don't.

My code works only with first span, because rest of account have prefix.

```
$("span").each(function(){
  var kodBanky = $(this).text().split("/")[1];      
  $('body').append("<p>" + kodBanky + "</p>");    
});
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GqpPdO?editors=1010)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few means of doing this, the basics are to find the last part and then use that last part:

```
// iterate over each <span>:
$("span").each(function() {
  // find the text of the current <span>, split
  // on the '/' characters, and retrieve that last
  // part:
  var kodBanky = $(this).text().split("/").pop();

  // append a newly created <p> element to the
  // <body> element:
  $('<p/>', {
    'text' : kodBanky
  }.appendTo('body');
});
```

```js
$("span").each(function() {
  var kodBanky = $(this).text().split("/").pop();
  $('body').append("<p>" + kodBanky + "</p>");
});
```

```css
span {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 0 0.5em 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>6456465465/0471</span>
<span>4547/6456465465/0471</span>
<span>4547/6465465/0471</span>
```

It's worth noting that jQuery is almost certainly not required for something so simple as this:

```
// get all the <span> elements in the document, and convert
// the returned collection, from document.querySelectorAll(),
// into an Array, using Array.from():
var spans = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('span')),

  // create a <p> element:
  para = document.createElement('p'),

  // two variables for later use:
  clone,
  code;

// iterating over the Array of <span> elements:
spans.forEach(function(span) {
  // 'span' refers to the current array-element,
  // a <span> element, within the array of <span>
  // elements over which we're iterating.

  // code is the text contained within the current
  // <span> after it's trimmed of its leading, and
  // trailing, white-space. We then split that text
  // on the '/' characters, and retrieve the last
  // Array element of the Array using
  // Array.prototype.pop()
  code = span.textContent.trim().split('/').pop();

  // we clone the paragraph:
  clone = para.cloneNode();

  // updating its textContent:
  clone.textContent = code;

  // and append that created-<p> element to
  // document.body:
  document.body.appendChild(clone);
});
```

```js
var spans = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('span')),
  para = document.createElement('p'),
  clone,
  code;

spans.forEach(function(span) {
  code = span.textContent.trim().split('/').pop();
  clone = para.cloneNode();

  clone.textContent = code;
  document.body.appendChild(clone);
});
```

```css
span {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 0 0.5em 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<span>6456465465/0471</span>
<span>4547/6456465465/0471</span>
<span>4547/6465465/0471</span>
```

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).
  - [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
  - [`Array.prototype.pop()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop).
  - [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
  - [`Node.cloneNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode).
  - [`Node.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent).
  - [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).
- jQuery:

  - [`appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/).
  - [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/).
  - [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

Answer (score 2):

Use **[`Array#pop()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop)** method to get last element from split array

```js
$("span").each(function(){
  var kodBanky = $(this).text().split("/").pop();
  $('body').append("<p>" + kodBanky + "</p>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>6456465465/0471</span>
<span>4547/6456465465/0471</span>
<span>4547/6465465/0471</span>
```

---

Although you can use **[`String#match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)** method or **[`String#slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice)** method

```js
$("span").each(function(){
  var kodBanky = $(this).text().match(/\d{4}$/)[0];
  // or
  // var kodBanky = $(this).text().slice(-4);
  $('body').append("<p>" + kodBanky + "</p>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>6456465465/0471</span>
<span>4547/6456465465/0471</span>
<span>4547/6465465/0471</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use substring from (string size - 4) to (string size)

```
var digits = yourSpanVar.substring(yourSpanVar.length-4, yourSpanVar.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help. This will give last 4 digit.

```
$("span").each(function(){
  var kodBanky = $(this).text();
      kodBanky = kodBanky.slice(-4);      
  $('body').append("<p>" + kodBanky + "</p>");    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use [String.lastIndexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf):

```js
$(function () {
 
  $("span").each(function(index, ele){
    var kodBanky = ele.textContent.substr(ele.textContent.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    $('body').append("<p>Result " + index + ' --> ' + kodBanky + "</p>");
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span>6456465465/0471</span><br>
<span>4547/6456465465/0471</span><br>
<span>4547/6465465/0471</span><br>
```

Another possible approach could be:

```js
$(function () {
  
  $("span").each(function(index, ele) {
    // look for the last match..
    var kodBanky = ele.textContent.split(/^.*\/([^/]+)$/).join('');
    $('body').append("<p>Result " + index + ' --> ' + kodBanky + "</p>");
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<span>6456465465/0471</span><br>
<span>4547/6456465465/0471</span><br>
<span>4547/6465465/0471</span><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick easily

```
var kodBanky = "";
$("span").each(function(){
  kodBanky = $(this).text();
  kodBanky =  kodBanky.substr(kodBanky.length - 4); 
  alert(kodBanky);
});
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/kk6avvp6/) here